# how to extract the text between single quotes?

Tags: desktop-background, wallch

I'm running **wallch** to automatically cycle thru my wallpapers. I have hundreds of them. I created a little application that displays the title of a wallpaper:

```
export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/bin/zenity --info --text="$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri | cut -c 41-)"
```

Without the cut, the output is:

```
'file:///home/frank/Pictures/Wallpapers/Sitka_Harbor.jpg'
```

with the cut, I get the file name:

```
Sitka_Harbor.jpg'
```

I want to get rid of the trailing apostrophe.  I've tried various combinations of the cut --output-delimiter, but can't seem to get it to work.

I would be grateful if someone could point me to some code that would return just the file name.

Thanking all,

sadhu

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
basename `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri` \'
```

assuming you are using BASH.

`basename` will extract the last name in the path, which is generated using your command to gsettings, put in backticks so it is seen as a command and not a string. The second argument to `basename` is the terminating characters you want to omit, in this case the apostrophe, which must be escaped using a backslash so it doesn't start a quote on the shell.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the file name, add:

```
| sed 's/\'//'
```

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to escape the apostrophes; they are interpreted by the shell. In any case, the solution from @Travis G. works without pipes. Here's the command line: 

`/usr/bin/zenity --info --text="$(basename `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri` \')"`